# Is it still thread safe if I do first() then pop_front()?

Tags: stl, qt4

Consider the following code in a multithread program:

```
    QString target = remaining.first(); // remaining is a QVector<QString> class
    remaining.pop_front();
```

Would it be safe? Looks like multiple thread may use the same "target" simultaneously. Or what's the safe way to retrieve + erase the first value?

Comment: Do you have a mutex around that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a mutex protecting that code, no, it's not at all safe.

I don't know `QVector` in detail but I believe it's OK for two threads to both do:

```
QString target = remaining.first();
```

This simply copies an element of the vector, so each thread has its own `QString` object called `target` and they are independent objects (behind the scenes they use [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html) so are not independent, but you should be able to [treat them as independent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes))

But this line modifies the `QVector`:

```
remaining.pop_front();
```

This means two threads modify the same object without any synchronisation. If the first thread is still accessing the vector by calling `remaining.first()` when the second thread calls `pop_front()` then there is a data race, with undefined behaviour.

Similarly, if both threads call `pop_front()` concurrently they will both try to remove the first element, what happens there is completely unpredictable. You might erase one element, or two, or none, or crash the entire program immediately.  As another possibility, consider what happens if the vector only has one element. Both threads check it's not empty, copy the `first()` element, then call `pop_front()`, which tries to remove two elements when there's only one. You're program is broken.

The safe way to do it is protect the code with a mutex, where `mutex` is some global or otherwise shared variable that is visible to both threads:

```
QString target;
{
  QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
  if (!remaining.empty())
  {
    target = remaining.first();
    remaining.pop_front();
  }
}
```